# How is the .sha256 file on the download page for Inkscape used as a checksum?

Tags: hashing

In Windows 10 I would like to download and install Inkscape 1.1.2, verifying the installation file first.

How do you view the contents of the .sha256 file (labeled 'sig' on the Inkscape download page) to compare with the checksum hash for Inkscape's latest stable download?

As the checksum hash of a file can be seen using powershell, can you also use powershell to see the contents of the .sha256 'sig' file? Can it be done without having to download further software?

Comment: It's just a plain text file.

Comment: @tom Thanks for your comment, so glad it will not be complicated to see, thought it would be after seeing that some code (that means nothing to me) was used here https://superuser.com/questions/1566136/is-the-sha256-file-format-formally-defined-somewhere-how-should-it-be-parsed for a .sha256 file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: In Windows, you may also use `certutil` to compute the hash.
For example:

```
certutil -hashfile C:/Users/user1/Downloads/software.zip SHA256
```

For answering your question, see the post
[How can I compare a file's SHA256 hash in PowerShell to a known value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396620/how-can-i-compare-a-files-sha256-hash-in-powershell-to-a-known-value),
quoted here:

The `Get-FileHash` cmdlet computes hashes for files, and [SHA256 is its default hash algorithm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7).

To compute the hash of a file:

```
Get-FileHash .\path\to\foo.zip
```

This produces something like:

```
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          15DC0502666851226F1D9C0FE352CCAF0FFDEFF2350B6D2D08A90FCD1F610A10       C:\Users\me\path\to\foo.zip
```

To compare to the known value, extract the computed hash value alone from the output of Get-FileHash, then compare it to the expected value as a (quoted) string literal. Conveniently this comparison appears to be case-insensitive

```
(Get-FileHash .\path\to\foo.zip).Hash -eq "15dc0502666851226f1d9c0fe352ccaf0ffdeff2350b6d2d08a90fcd1f610a10"
```

```
True
```

...or if you've got the expected hash in a file, say `expected-hash.sha256`

```
(Get-FileHash '.\path\to\foo.zip').Hash -eq (Get-Content .\expected-hash.sha256)
```

```
True
```